# Append options to select box depend on extracted part from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 selectboxs moduleName, submoduleName, ProgrameName and last selectbox has all data for username, module, submodule and programe name merged and splited with ";" between each other, I need: when user select module name from moduleName Selectbox it filters values in all data selectbox and splites submoduleNames under this moduleName and append it as options to submoduleName Selectbox, also the same when user select from submoduleName selectbox it filters programeNames under this module and subModuleNames and append it as options in programeName selectbox. I tried to splite each line in allData selectbox but i failed to continue. here what i tried but it is not working.
Thank you for your help.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  function check(){
    var lines = $('#splitedOptions').val().split(/\n/);
    var texts = [];
    for (var i=1; i < lines.length; i++) {
      texts.push(lines[i]);
    }

    for (var i=0; i < texts.length; i++) {
      var extractedPart = texts[i].split(';'),
          ModuleNameVal = $("#moduleName option:selected").val();

      if(extractedPart[1] == ModuleNameVal){
        var newOption = "<option value='"+extractedPart[2]+"'>"+extractedPart[2]+"</option>";
        $('#SubModuleName').append(newOption);
      } 
    }
  }

  function c1() {
    var optionsCount = $('#allData').find('option').size();
    var textArea ="";
    for (var i = 1; i <= optionsCount; i++) {
      if(i!=1){
        textArea += '\n';
      }
      var xItem = $('#allData').find('option:nth-child(' + (i) + ')').text(); 
      textArea +=  xItem ;
    }
    $('#splitedOptions').val('');
    $('#splitedOptions').val(textArea);
    check();
  }
  $('#moduleName').change(function(){
    c1()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>ModuleName:</label>
<select class="moduleName" id="moduleName">
 <option value="HR">HR</option>
 <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
 <option value="Purchase">Purchase</option>
 <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
</select><br><br>

<label>SubModuleName:</label>
<select class="SubModuleName" id="SubModuleName"></select><br><br>

<label>ProgrameName:</label>
<select class="programeName" id="programeName"></select><br><br>

<label>All Data:</label>
<select class="allData" id="allData">
  <option value="userName;HR;Transactions;EmployeeMaster">Option1</option>
  <option value="userName;HR;Master;EmployeeMaster">Option2</option>
  <option value="userName;Marketing;Master;MarketingMaster">Option3</option>
  <option value="userName;HR;Reports;HRReports">Option4</option>
  <option value="userName;Purchase;PurchaseOrders;LPO">Option5</option>
  <option value="userName;Purchase;PurchaseOrders;IPO">Option6
  <option value="userName;Finance;Master;FinanceMasterPrograme">Option7</option>
  <option value="userName;Finance;Reports;FinanceReportsPrograme">Option8</option>
</select><br><br>
  
  <label>splited Options:</label>
  <textarea id="splitedOptions" name="splitedOptions" ></textarea>
```

Comment: If user select any value in `SubModuleName` so how the other dropdown will get load ? I am not seeing anything similar you have `MarketingMaster...` how to differentiate them ?

Comment: Each option in All Data select box has user name, Module, sub module, programe name splited with ";" For example: if user select Marketing from ModuleName select box, it search in All Data select box options and filter the option has Marketing after user name then extract Master word from this option and load in SubModuleName select box and if user select Master from SubModuleName select box it search in All Data select box options and filter the option that has Marketing as a module and Master as a SubModuleName then extract programe name from that options and load it in programe name select.

Comment: In our case programe name will be MarketingMaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve above is to `filter` the options from `allData` select-box and get only those option which has the `value` which user has selected  using `value*="yourvalue"`.

Then , onces you get the options you need to know which select-box has been change so that we can get required value only when we do `split` and pass required index .

Lastly , we need to loop through the options which we have got from filtering select-box .Suppose user select `Master` so there are `Master` in many places so to avoid getting data from all option i have check the value of select with the first select-box as well if matches apppend only those options.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('select').change(function() {
//get value
  var name = $(this).val();
  //filter option and get only option which has the value which user has slected
  var s = $("#allData").find('option').filter('[value*=' + name + ']').each(function(ele) {
    return $(this).val();
  });
  var module_namess;
  var index;
  //check the id of select-box
  if ($(this).attr("id") == "moduleName") {
    module_namess = "SubModuleName";
    index = 2;//set index 
  } else if ($(this).attr("id") == "SubModuleName") {
    name = $("#moduleName").val()
    module_namess = "programeName"
    index = 3
  }

  $("#" + module_namess).empty()
  $('#' + module_namess).append("<option >Select one</option>")
  var valuess = ''
  //loop through options
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    valuess += $(s[i]).val()
    //if first value is same
    if ($(s[i]).val().split(";")[1] == name) {
        var sub_value = $(s[i]).val().split(";")[index]//get the value 
      var newOption = "<option value='" + sub_value + "'>" + sub_value + "</option>";
      $('#' + module_namess).append(newOption);//append
    }
  }
  $('#splitedOptions').val(valuess);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>ModuleName:</label>
<select class="moduleName" id="moduleName">
  <option value="HR">HR</option>
  <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
  <option value="Purchase">Purchase</option>
  <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
</select><br><br>

<label>SubModuleName:</label>
<select class="SubModuleName" id="SubModuleName"></select><br><br>

<label>ProgrameName:</label>
<select class="programeName" id="programeName"></select><br><br>

<label>All Data:</label>
<select class="allData" id="allData">
  <option value="userName;HR;Transactions;EmployeeMaster">Option1</option>
  <option value="userName;HR;Master;EmployeeMaster">Option2</option>
  <option value="userName;Marketing;Master;MarketingMaster">Option3</option>
  <option value="userName;HR;Reports;HRReports">Option4</option>
  <option value="userName;Purchase;PurchaseOrders;LPO">Option5</option>
  <option value="userName;Purchase;PurchaseOrders;IPO">Option6
    <option value="userName;Finance;Master;FinanceMasterPrograme">Option7</option>
    <option value="userName;Finance;Reports;FinanceReportsPrograme">Option8</option>
</select><br><br>

<label>splited Options:</label>
<textarea id="splitedOptions" name="splitedOptions"></textarea>
```

Comment: You are greet! Thank you.